# fstab: Email address as curlftpfs username

Tags: linux, fstab, fuse

I want to mount a ftp share via the fstab file but my username is an email address. How do I enter this in the fstab?

```
john@example.com:foobar@ftp.example.com,
"john@example.com":foobar@ftp.example.com
```

and

```
john\@example.com:foobar@ftp.example.com
```

did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, got it. user=... in the options and it works.